# Inverse Function Multi-Variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following function:

\begin{array}{rccc}
  \xi\colon&\mathbb{R}^2 &\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}^3\\
   &(u,v) &\mapsto&(u,v^2,v^3).
\end{array}

I need to show this function is a homeomorphism, i.e., $\xi$ has an inverse map which is continuous.

I really do not know where to begin.

Any hints?

Comment: Try first the simpler function
$$
(u, v) \mapsto \left(u, v^3\right).
$$
If that is still hard, try showing that the single-variable function
$$
v \mapsto v^3
$$
is a homeomorphism.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense unless you tell us which set is $U$.

Comment: @avs yes, in that case, the inverse functio would be defined as $(u,v) \to (u,v^\frac{1}{3})$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes, I'm sorry..my bad. We are in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Don't even know why I wrote $U$ in the first place. I will edit the question! But it still does not make sense to me cause, as we are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the inverse will not have one single expression. Should I write both of them and show that the piecewise function is continuous? Am I thinking wrong ?

Comment: Then your function will be a homeomorphism onto its image.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm sorry if it is not clear to me but...how do you conclude that that easily ?

Comment: For this question, as with the example that @avs suggested, you can produce the inverse function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take$$U=\xi(\Bbb R^2)=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\,\middle|\,y^3=z^2\right\}.$$Then $\xi$ is a homeomorphism from $\Bbb R^2$ onto $U$, whose inverse is$$\begin{array}{rccc}\xi^{-1}\colon&U&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R^2\\&(x,y,z)&\mapsto&\left(x,\sqrt[3]z\right),\end{array}$$which is continuous.

Comment: thank you very much sir! It was really helpful! obrigado!